# Python Timestamp Regular Expression

Tags: python, timestamp, expression

Can someone help me with my code where I have written data from a csv file into the timeStamp list?  The data in the list is currently formatted like so 03.08.2012 07.11.15 PM.  And I need the just the time 07:11:15 PM to be put into the `actTime` array.  Here is my code:

```
import csv
import re
reader = csv.reader(open('main.csv','rb'), delimiter=',',quotechar="'")
timeStamp = []
ask = []
regexp = re.compile('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{4}')
actTime = []
x = 0
try:
    for row in reader:
        ask.append(row[5:6])
        timeStamp.append(row[7:8])
except csv.Error, e:
    sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
for item in timeStamp:
    actTime.append(timeStamp[x])
    match = regexp.match(timeStamp[x])
    if match:
        time = int(match.group[x])
    x = x + 1
```

Here is the error message I am getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "rates.py", line 17, in 
>           match = regexp.match(timeStamp[x])
>       TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: In `timeStamp.append(row[7:8])` you are appending *lists* containing exactly one element to the timeStamp list.  Afterwards you pass this list to `regexp.match()`, which expects a string, not a list.  Did you mean: `timeStamp.append(row[7])`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [built-in timestamp parsing mechanism](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) instead.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t = "03.08.2012 07.11.15 PM"
>>> u = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%d.%m.%Y %I.%M.%S %p")
>>> u
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 3, 19, 11, 15)
>>> u.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
'07:11:15 PM'
```

Answer (score 1):

`row[7:8]` is a list of length 1, not a string. `regexp` needs a string. Use `row[7]` instead.

Comment: How would I add just the time into a new list?  For example I only want 07:11:15 PM in a new list.  Thank you.

Comment: Different question, right? Depends on what your timestamp looks like. You can probably get it with `stamp[:11]` (e.g. `row[7][:11]`)